# How do I merge multiple, small PDF's into a single one using PDFBox without running out of heap space?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I have been attempting to merge multiple, smaller PDF's (6 MB is the largest I have used thus far), into a single PDF. Any time I attempt to use more than 14 MB of input, I get an Out of Memory error.

When merging, the memory usage for the process jumps to over 550MB. That seems excessive for 14MB of input.

I am running this application on an IBM Websphere Application Server, locally, using PDFBox version 1.8.5

I have increased the heap size to 1024MB, and while this allowed me to use a few more files for input, I quickly run up against the same issue.

At the suggestion of a commenter, I have changed the methodology to merge pairs of documents together then further merge previously merged pairs. This allowed me to get further than I had before. I still get an Out of Memory error with files around 30 MB in size, but it is much more workable.

```
File sourceLoc = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "source_files");
File scratch = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "scratch.txt");
PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();

merger.setDestinationFileName(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "merged.pdf");
for(File file : sourceLoc.listFiles())
    merger.addSource(file);
merger.mergeDocumentsNonSeq(new org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFile(scratch, "rw"));
```

This is the log generated:

```
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at      2014/08/01 13:01:50 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using 'C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\core.20140801.130150.2408.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I System dump written to C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\core.20140801.130150.2408.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using 'C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\heapdump.20140801.130150.2408.0002.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\heapdump.20140801.130150.2408.0002.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using 'C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\javacore.20140801.130150.2408.0003.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\javacore.20140801.130150.2408.0003.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using 'C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\Snap.20140801.130150.2408.0004.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to C:\Working\IntranetApps\I-Document\Services\Snap.20140801.130150.2408.0004.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.clone(RandomAccessBuffer.java:69)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.clone(COSStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.<init>(COSStream.java:96)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parseCOSStream(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:1513)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parseObjectDynamically(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:1266)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parseObjectDynamically(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:1192)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parseDictObjects(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:1166)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.initialParse(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:479)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.parse(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:740)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.loadNonSeq(PDDocument.java:1306)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.loadNonSeq(PDDocument.java:1289)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:232)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocumentsNonSeq(PDFMergerUtility.java:201)
    at com.my.pkg.MyMergeClass.main(MyMergeClass.java:90)
```

Comment: Are you running your application on a Tomcat server ?

Comment: Increase the heap space and try again, If problem persist please update.

Comment: IBM WAS server. I increased the heap, and it allowed for more inputs, but I still run out of heap after a few more inputs are added. I edited question to include this information. Is this amount of overhead expected?

Comment: Have you tried merging the documents in sets of two rather than merging them all together at once? Keeping all the various PDF data structures in memory in a way that allows them to be merged quickly is bound to be expensive.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, Your Spaciness. I shall give it a try and update with my findings.

Comment: If this problem keeps happening, please create a small non-server related application that reproduces the problem with non-confidential PDFs and then open an issue in PDFBox JIRA, so that we can check whether there's a memory leak.

Comment: Space Pope, you may want to put your idea into an answer, as it has allowed for the most progress so far, and it is a much better response than "just figure out how to handle running OOM well".\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFs are mostly postscript, which is a language of its own... so 14MB of input can be anything from zero to infinite output.  Your best bet is to just figure out how to handle running OOM well.